# switch project to dev mode

Tags: debugging

I faced to problem trying drupal console:

1) In documentation written (https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/theming/twig/debugging-compiled-twig-templates):

```
drupal site:mode de
```

But I haven't that command in a list of other commands when I attempt drupal list in a project root

2) Then when I put in settings.php or settings.local.php this:

```
$settings['cache']['bins']['render'] = 'cache.backend.null';
$settings['cache']['bins']['dynamic_page_cache'] = 'cache.backend.null';
```

I got Error...

```
The website encountered an unexpected error. Please try again later.
Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Exception\ServiceNotFoundException: You have requested a non-existent service "cache.backend.null". Did you mean one of these: "cache.backend.apcu", "cache.backend.php", "cache.backend.memory"? in Drupal\Component\DependencyInjection\Container->get() (line 157 of core/lib/Drupal/Component/DependencyInjection/Container.php).
Drupal\Component\DependencyInjection\Container->get('cache.backend.null') (Line: 83)
Drupal\Core\Cache\CacheFactory->get('render')
call_user_func_array(Array, Array) (Line: 254)
Drupal\Component\DependencyInjection\Container->createService(Array, 'cache.render') (Line: 177)
Drupal\Component\DependencyInjection\Container->get('cache.render', 1) (Line: 494)
Drupal\Component\DependencyInjection\Container->resolveServicesAndParameters(Array) (Line: 236)
Drupal\Component\DependencyInjection\Container->createService(Array, 'http_middleware.page_cache') (Line: 177)
Drupal\Component\DependencyInjection\Container->get('http_middleware.page_cache', 1) (Line: 494)
Drupal\Component\DependencyInjection\Container->resolveServicesAndParameters(Array) (Line: 236)
Drupal\Component\DependencyInjection\Container->createService(Array, 'http_middleware.reverse_proxy') (Line: 177)
Drupal\Component\DependencyInjection\Container->get('http_middleware.reverse_proxy', 1) (Line: 494)
Drupal\Component\DependencyInjection\Container->resolveServicesAndParameters(Array) (Line: 236)
Drupal\Component\DependencyInjection\Container->createService(Array, 'http_middleware.negotiation') (Line: 177)
Drupal\Component\DependencyInjection\Container->get('http_middleware.negotiation', 1) (Line: 494)
Drupal\Component\DependencyInjection\Container->resolveServicesAndParameters(Array) (Line: 236)
Drupal\Component\DependencyInjection\Container->createService(Array, 'http_kernel') (Line: 177)
Drupal\Component\DependencyInjection\Container->get('http_kernel') (Line: 1320)
Drupal\Core\DrupalKernel->getHttpKernel() (Line: 652)
Drupal\Core\DrupalKernel->handle(Object) (Line: 19)
```

If someone resolved it please share)

Comment: Hello @igorpromen. Can you update your question with the actual error you're facing? Thanks!

Comment: Hello, first is absence of command (site:mode)
Second: edited in question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1 It appears that there is no site:mode command in the latest drupal console (1.0.0-rc16), but instead site:maintenance (sma) (on/off) is available. Maybe they ditched site:mode at some point because site:maintenance made more sense in Drupal context.

2 Make sure you have this code in development.services.yml:

```
services:
  cache.backend.null:
    class: Drupal\Core\Cache\NullBackendFactory
```

Comment: thank you, I have to have read attentively the instructions in settings.php and settings.local.php before serfing on the internet)) but for the maintenance mode thanks a lot)

Comment: turn on maintenance mode:


$ drupal site:maintenance on